# What is the termcap code for the caret (aka circumflex) (^) key?

Tags: terminal, vim, keycode, termcap

I want to remap the `^` key to `<Esc>` in VIM since it is easier to reach on a german keyboard. As far as I understand there is no keycode for the `^` key and I have to use the termcap notation:

```
inoremap <t_*> <Esc>     " remap ^ to ESC
inoremap <C-t_*> <t_*>   " map CTRL-^ to the plain ^ (insert a '^' char)
```

But I could not find the termcap code for the circumlflex `^`. Does anybody know a complete list of termcap codes for typical terminals. I want this solution to work for gvim in Ubuntu and Windows.

**Edit:** `inoremap ^ <Esc>` in Linux works partially. You have to press `^^`. It only works perfectly if you use a non-dead-key layout. `inoremap <C-^> ^` also does work fine with a non-dead-key layout but does not work at all with the default layout.

**Solution:** Use a keyboard layout that does not mute the `^` key and use the `^` (aka. circumflex or caret) as a std. ASCII character in your ~/.vimrc.

See [superuser.com/questions/280005](https://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout), how to disable dead keys in Windows. Thx Jens for the link.

Thx, Juve

Comment: Do `inoremap ^ <esc>` and `inoremap <c-^> ^` work?

Comment: It works in Linux. But I am using a nodead-key layout there. I guess that makes the trick. In Windows I have a normal german layout where pressing `^` wont do anything until you press another key. There the `inoremap ^ <Esc>` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret `^` is a regular ASCII character; it stands for itself and does not produce any termcap/terminfo sequence, so what you attempt with `<t_*>` is futile.
Try to find out how to turn off dead keys on windows and you're done with ib's solution.

Comment: The ASCII char is produced when I press the `^` a second time. So I'd still be interested in the termcap code for the first `^` press. I thought every key has a termcap code, even the default ASCII chars?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. It's the keyboard driver that initially creates the sequence of characters an application receives. Only then is termcap/terminfo used to map these sequences to some action, e.g. the terminal sends <Esc>OA for the UpArrow Key, and using termcap the application knows that the abstract function "Cursor Up" is requested. Dead keys are a lower level function of the X-Server/Windows-Keyboard Driver.

Comment: OK,I get it. So vim won't get any sequence until I press the second `^`. because the keyboard driver intercepts the first.

Comment: Right. Over on Superuser `dead-keys` is a tag :-) Maybe this thread will help you turning off dead keys: http://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout

Comment: Thx, for the link. My Windows at work is now also equipped with a non-dead caret.